# Command "look" optimisation (virtual linebreaks)

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

(I am not totally sure if this question ONLY belongs to Ubuntu but rather to all OS supporting a command line or shell)

**~/.bashrc | ~/.zshrc**

```
alias proxyon='export FTP_PROXY=http://ftp-proxy.intern.me.de:1234; export HTTPS_PROXY=http://https-proxy.intern.me.de:1234; export HTTP_PROXY=http://http-proxy.intern.me.de:2222; export ftp_proxy=http://ftp-proxy.intern.me.de:2222; export http_proxy=http://http-proxy.intern.me.de:3333; export https_proxy=http://https-proxy.intern.me.de:3333; export no_proxy="localhost, 127.0.0.1, *.intern.me.de,*.admin-test.de, *.admin-live.me.de"'
```

I want a more eye-friendly formating of this like:

```
alias proxyon='
export FTP_PROXY=http://ftp-proxy.intern.me.de:1234; 
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://https-proxy.intern.me.de:1234;
export HTTP_PROXY=http://http-proxy.intern.me.de:2222;
export ftp_proxy=http://ftp-proxy.intern.me.de:2222;
export http_proxy=http://http-proxy.intern.me.de:3333;
export https_proxy=http://https-proxy.intern.me.de:3333;
export no_proxy="localhost, 127.0.0.1, *.intern.me.de,*.admin-test.de, *.admin-live.me.de"'
```

inside my editor or on my wiki/confluence.
But pasting it into bash would not work (of course becourse '\n' will destroy the command.

Is there something usefull I can add to anny line, so that c'N'p is possible also I added a nicely view  (with breaks) in my file/wiki?

Greatings

Comment: *"would not work"* Did you actually try it? what was the error (if any)?

Comment: You could use [bash functions](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) instead of aliases.

Answer (score 0):

I tried part of what you gave and it works for me

```
$ cat .alias
alias proxyon='
export FTP_PROXY=http://ftp-proxy.intern.me.de:1234; 
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://https-proxy.intern.me.de:1234; '
```

and the result is

```
$ env | grep PROXY
FTP_PROXY=http://ftp-proxy.intern.me.de:1234
HTTPS_PROXY=http://https-proxy.intern.me.de:1234
```